# Проверять действия и отправлять сообщение C# telegram api

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня код проверяет дату, и если дата верная,то он отправялет в беседу картинку, но пока моему боту сообщение кто-то не напишет, он не проверяет её, как мне это обойти? 
Bот кусокчек кода :

```
try
  {
  var proxy = new HttpToSocks5Proxy(".....", ....);
  TelegramBotClient tgbot = new TelegramBotClient("...",proxy);
  var me = tgbot.GetMeAsync().Result;
  Console.WriteLine(me.Id + me.Username + me.FirstName);

         tgbot.StartReceiving();
      tgbot.SetWebhookAsync("...");
    tgbot.OnMessage += getmessage;
    tgbot.OnMessage += SentImage.video;//тут класс в котором идет проверка на дату и отправка картинки. Когда сообщения не приходят, он ничего из своих действий не делает
      Console.ReadLine();
         }catch(AggregateException ee)
         { Console.WriteLine(ee); };
```

Я думаю проблемма в Webhook,то что он сам присылает, когда случилось какое-то событие в телеграмм, но могу быть не прав. Если есть какие-то вопросы, пишпите в комментарии, если надо докину еще куски кода..

Comment: `...но пока моему боту сообщение кто-то не напишет, он не проверяет её...` а разве может быть иначе? Бот -- обычная программа, которая на вход принимает текстовые команды, а на выход отдает какую-то инфу. Пока команда не поступила, никакой инфы не будет.

Comment: А без команды, нельзя проверку делать, может можно как-то делать проверку, при каком-то произошедшем событии? Например в какой-то группе пришло сообщение. Впринципе я ответил только что на свой вопрос. И да, бот не только принимает команды, есть разные боты.